# How to unversion a folder in SVN?

Tags: svn

I've read similar questions here. So, let me start with

**Why this is not duplicate?**

I'm copying the folder in my backup folder, which is not a working copy, and then trying to unversion the folder. It is not working, hence this question.

I copied my maven project from working folder to my backup folder, which is not versioned in svn. When I copied the files, I see SVN is connected to that folder (I see green tick marks on files), I've no idea how :|. Probably it is because of some files which svn put in working folder, not sure. So, when I tried unversioning the folder I see following error,

[image]

How do I unversion a svn folder, which is not in a working copy/folder?

**Note:** I don't want to unversion my working copy & then copy. As after copying to backup I'll have to add it to svn again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for `.svn` directories and remove them in the backup. These directories are hidden, so you should configure File Explorer to show hidden items.

[SVNBook | Creating a Working Copy](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/initial/):

> **What is This .svn Directory?**
>   The topmost directory of a working copy—and prior
>   to version 1.7, every versioned subdirectory thereof—contains a
>   special administrative subdirectory named .svn. Usually, your
>   operating system's directory listing commands won't show this
>   subdirectory, but it is nevertheless an important directory. Whatever
>   you do, don't delete or change anything in the administrative area!
>   Subversion uses that directory and its contents to manage your working
>   copy.

Comment: Awesome! I knew there should be something which svn puts in folder for it to recognize svn directory. Thanks to you, that I know what is it exactly!!

Comment: Better to use SVN commands to remove them, like using "svn export" rather than doing a blind copy in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You may look at [this page](http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html).
Be sure also to check for hidden files in your folder, which relate to the svn versioning system.

Comment: The problem is my folder is not the working copy! I can't unversion working copy.

Comment: This link-only answer is actually the correct answer, if it is expanded to give the details. It is saying, you should use "svn export" from your working copy, to create the copy in the first place. Or, after you created your copy, what you actually did was create a *new* working copy. The link in this answer shows how to make that copy no longer a working copy.